# LinearLayout Beneath LinearLayout full width?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an ImageView and a TextView that are the only items in my Android UI. Currently the TextView is in the same LinearLayout as the ImageView, so the text sometimes runs to 2 lines. I want to get the text on its own line, with the full width of the parent element so it will be the whole width of the screen. So far everything I've tried moves the ImageView outside the window or makes it very small.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_imageview_gototags"
            android:src="@drawable/img_main_gototags"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:onClick="imageViewGoToTagsOnClickOnClick"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview_tagline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activity_main_textview_tagline"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you want text to be displayed below the image or overlapping and above the image ?

Comment: @dora below the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_imageview_gototags"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="imageViewGoToTagsOnClickOnClick"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_textview_tagline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="lfhjdhkjfhkjdhkjfhkdhkjfhdkshfkhskahdfkjdhkhkjfhdk"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps.let me know if it did not.

Comment: this is actually super duper close. How can I make it align in the center both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: that's almost it. I can't see what you changed, but I need to make the image align in the center horizontally as well.

Comment: edited it again. upvote the answer if it helps. In the previous edit i have put gravity of the parent layout to center and made the parents layout height match the parent.

Comment: YES! This is exactly it. Thank you a bunch. I am not able to upvote just yet, but as soon as I can I will come back and give you one. I have marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the parent(`LinearLayout`) of your `ImageView` a width of `0dp` make it `match_parent` instead and the same for your `TextView` also there's a property on text views `android:maxLines` that corresponds to how many lines at max can it go to, set it to 1 and if you need truncation you can also use `android:ellipsize` on the text view.

Comment: Making the     layout_width="match_parent"     makes the whole imageview the size of the window. I want that to maintain it's ratio of 50%, but the TextView to math_parent

Comment: alright I just experimented, then keep your `LinearLayout`'s width to 0dp and change the `TextView`'s width to `match_parent` along with `maxLines=1` That should work fine

Comment: that just makes it so if the text overflows the parent element (which is 50% of the screen) the line will truncate. I am looking to make it so the TextView sits below the image, with a full width (in this case the parent's parent).

Comment: Ah that's a tricky one I cannot think of a way to do it in xml give it a shot programatically by calculating the height and width of your root layout and keep a `RelativeLayout` for root then adjust you `ImageView`'s size as how you'd expect the linear layout to adjust it with weight property and put the `TextView` below it. A bit of experimenting should get you the result you're after

Comment: Yeah I can accomplish a pretty good result pragmatically, I was just hoping to find a way to do it completely static in XML. Thanks for your help though!